# Is this structure somehow infinitely recursive?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I haven't tried implementing this yet, because I'm trying to stay in the 'design phase' at the moment, but I'm trying to determine if this kind of structure is safe, or if it will get me laughed at:

[image: terrible class diagram]

In other words, a Student object contains an array containing Subjects, representing the subjects they have enrolled in/completed. A Subject contains an array of all the Students who are doing the subject. I'm concerned that implemented this way, each Subject within the array in Student also contains its own array of Students, each containing their own array of Subjects, ad infinitum.

Now, I understand that Java doesn't 'copy' these objects, but I'm still concerned that this would essentially create infinitely many references to those objects, which seems to me to be almost as bad an idea? Java being my first serious language, I am not familiar with memory management at all.

Edit: I know there are better ways of doing this involving bridge objects. And I know that it doesn't duplicate the objects themselves. What I'm afraid of is the copying of the cascading references themselves. Do references themselves 'duplicate' in this way, and does it consume any memory to have another reference to the same object? Or put differently, does the compiler/program at runtime try to 'follow' a cascading/looping chain like this, or does it mostly leave it alone, barring specific cases like toString() which someone mentioned in the comments?

Comment: You will surely make a database of `Student` and `Subject`  right ??

Comment: Why not introduce a `Course` object that has both the subject and the list of students in it? No point having the subject know who's taking it.

Comment: If I carry a slip of paper around with your name on it, and you carry a slip of paper with my name on it, are there infinitely many slips of paper?

Comment: Basically, in Java it's not correct to say each `Subject` has its own array of students.  It's really an array of _references_ to `Students`.  Sort of like how I can put a slip of paper with your name in my pocket, but I'm not really putting _you_ in my pocket.

Comment: I should probably add that I'm not allowed to change much in the code I've been given, but I'm expected to add functionality. I know, this isn't very realistic, or good practice, but as far as I know I'm stuck with Subjects containing arrays of Students. Giving each Student an array of Subjects is an attempt to add some features we're supposed to add while retaining a kind of symmetry, but I'm increasingly sure that repeating the original mistake can only make things worse...

Comment: @ajb it was the references I was concerned about, since my (limited) understanding is that the value of the reference (the pointer itself) is copied, even though the whole object isn't duplicated in memory, the tiny bit of data required to point to it is....

Comment: if you have a `Course` object , it will be easier to maintain and you can still add the functionalities to your `Student` object ...!

Comment: I don't see why you see this as a mistake.  Seems like a rather normal design to me.  If you haven't quite grasped the concept of references, though, then I could understand why this looks like a problem to you.

Comment: Right, references can be copied.  If a Student is doing six Subjects, then there will be six Subject objects that have references to that same Student.  But I'm not sure how you go from there to worrying about there being infinitely many references

Comment: But what if each subject contains a thousand students, each of whom have 20 subjects in their transcript?
I just see it as a mistake because the redundancy contradicts what I have learned in my database design units - Like a couple of people have suggested, I'd want to be making bridge objects, and ideally I'd want to implement it in SQL, not Java. I think I understand you now anyway -  the references in Student point directly to the original Course objects, and vice versa; memory is only occupied by the original objects (including the array of references to other objects). Is that right?

Comment: This is not really wrong, but you _could_ cause an infinite recursion in the `toString` methods:  If a `Student` string includes all that student's `Subject`s, and a `Subject` string includes all its assigned `Student`s...

Comment: You're pretty much right about the memory usage.  As for what you learned about database design... keep in mind that Java is somewhat lower-level than SQL.  In Java, you pretty much have to tell it what references you're keeping.  Your `Subject` has an array of references to `Students`, and that's all you get; Java won't create any additional fields for you.  In SQL, though, the database system is going to add indexes and stuff to make it efficient to get all the subjects that a student is taking or get all the students studying a subject....

Comment: ... and I'd guess that if you look at the actual data that SQL stores implicitly, it may have recursive references in it too.  However, I don't really know anything about how SQL implements databases.

Comment: To answer your last question: the compiler pretty much leaves things alone.  You won't get any problem unless you have a method that tries to follow every reference, using reflection to see what references there are.  `toString()` won't be a problem, either, unless you write an overriding `toString()` method that causes a problem; be careful about letting an IDE such as Eclipse generate the `toString()` methods for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it "infinitely recursive"? Not for any normal definition of the concept of recursion. Is it going to make a huge amount of references? Potentially, if implemented very poorly. In addition, if you are loading from a dB or other store, and not caching you actually could get full objects, which could be a significant problem.

There is a few ways those sort of problems are generally tackled.
First, generally you make collection references "lazy-load" as much as possible. So, for instance, I wouldn't load all students for a subject until the students property was accessed. Similarly I wouldn't load all subjects for a student unless the subjects property was accessed. By doing so, it becomes difficult for this to be problematic since code would, for all intents have to be malicious to make a huge number of copies. (Alternating between accessing all students for a subject, and the going back to subjects.) Could be done though.

Second, generally you try to make these sort of cyclomatic dependencies as rare as possible. I say as rare as possible because sometimes the domain problem you are modeling just really has that sort of relationship, and it is important to represent it.

Comment: all this discussion has more or less straightened this out for me I think: it won't loop forever, because it won't try and 'follow' the reference in the array under normal conditions... UNLESS i was dumb enough to do something like make a method that returns all students in a subject, and a method that returns all subjects in a student, and then fed them to each other - the kind of malicious implementation you're thinking of?

Comment: Precisely what I was thinking of. Just don't populate the collections until you reference them (lazy load) and it won't do anything evil

Comment: In my humble opinion 2nd comment to the question is a better and right way of handling this relationship.

Comment: Like I said in the second part of my answer, it is best to avoid this sort of cylomatic dependency, no argument there. Changing how you think of the relationships, even if only a little can help you see a less coupled design. But I tried to present both sides, and lazy loading is an important concept regardless of the modeling approach.